# writing a text into xml file on click of a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

can any one tell me the procedure to write a text on to the xml file from the text box ,on click of the button.As im new to the iphone applications,please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following answers.

For "light-weight", plain text writing:
[Writing and reading text files on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964274/writing-and-reading-text-files-on-the-iphone)

A more elaborate approach:
[Writing files on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522476/writing-files-on-iphone)

Good luck!